# Show that it is an algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

This excercise is a little struggling for me. The part I need help with is showing that $D$ is closed under complements.

Let $C$ denote the collection of all intervals on $\mathbb{R}$, including degenerate intervals of the form $[a,a]$ and $(a,a)$. And let $D$ be the collection of finite disjoint unions of members of $C$. Prove that $D$ is an algebra. Hint: First show that $D$ is closed under intersection and then under complementation.

Now, here is my attempt to show it is closed under complementation.

Let $A \in D$.

Then $A = A_1\cup A_2....\cup A_{N_A}$. Where each $A_i$ is an interval, and all of them are disjoint.

We have that $A^C=A_1^C\cap A_2^C....\cap A_{N_A}^C$.  But I need to show that $A^C$ is a finite union of disjoint intervals. I can see it drawing that it must be so, because if we have $N_A$ original intervals we can see that the remaining part of $\mathbb{R}$ also must be disjoint intervals. But is this enough of a mathematical proof?

Comment: If you have already shown that $D$ is closed under intersection, you only need to show that $A_k^c$, the complement of an interval, is a disjoint union of intervals.

Comment: @DanielFischer Smart, thanks, and I guess that is something that is kind of obvious. The complement of an interval must be a union of disjoint intervals. I guess maybe I should go through all possibly cases, but it won't be so many, thanks!